# GeoDjango: Clustering of large number of markers

Tags: django, google-maps, google-maps-markers, geodjango, markerclusterer

Hi Stackoverflow people,

I started using GeoDjango and I was very happy when I came across the Google map v2 implementation `django.contrib.gis.maps.google.overlays`. Not the newest anymore, since v2 is depreciated, but still a very compact tools to simply display markers on a map with

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
{{ google.xhtml }}
<head>
  {{ google.style }}
  {{ google.scripts }}
</head>
<body onload="{{ google.js_module }}.map_load()" onunload="GUnload()">
  <div id="{{ google.dom_id }}" style="width:600px; height:400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code taken from [here](http://jefurii.cafejosti.net/blog/2011/05/05/basic-google-maps-django/).

Based on this very compact code, how can I implement a [clustering function](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/simple_example.html?)? I have read that clustering is not supported by GeoDjango at the moment. **Has anyone implemented clustering by using the `django.contrib.gis.maps.google.overlays`? Or is it the better way to write the full function myself and loop through all list entries to create the markers?**

Thank you for sharing your experience and suggestions.

Comment: kmeans is the common method used for clustering, do a search for that here.  You'll probably need to implement your own view taking into account a bbox and zoomlevel.

Comment: I *dont* understand why this is voted down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try my geodjango clustering app for server-side clustering:

https://github.com/biodiv/anycluster

It uses kmeans and/or grid.

Comment: Interesting stuff. I wrote something like that in C++ and use it as a command line utility from inside web apps, but now that I think of it doing it in the database seems more appropriate and scalable. Thanks for sharing!